# Disabling the tableView when Datepicker cell is selected

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uidatepicker

I have a date picker with tool par which pops up when one of the cells of the table view is selected. I want the table view to be disabled when the date picker is shown.

UITableViewCell:

```
func populateWithField(fieldType: EnrollmentDetailsFields?, value: String?) {
        self.fieldType = fieldType
         ....
        textField.text = value
       datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.UANeutralWhite
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        if let toolBarView = self.getInputAccessoryButtonsForTypes([KeyboardAccessoryButtonTypes.previous, KeyboardAccessoryButtonTypes.next, KeyboardAccessoryButtonTypes.clear, KeyboardAccessoryButtonTypes.done], target: self, doneButtonAction: #selector(doneButtonClicked), clearButtonAction: #selector(clearButtonClicked), nextButtonAction: #selector(nextButtonClicked), previousButtonAction: #selector(previousButtonClicked)) {
            datePicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.datePickerWithToolBar.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                   datePicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.datePickerWithToolBar.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                   datePicker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.datePickerWithToolBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        toolBarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePicker.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            toolBarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
            textField.inputView = datePicker
            textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBarView
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
                datePickerWithToolBar.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        }
    }
```

How can I have the date picker as something below. I want the screen behind the date picker to be disabled.

[image: I am trying to create something like this]

Answer (score 0):

You can have a callback inside the cell custom class like

```
var callBackEnabled:((Bool) ->())?
```

then do

```
callBackEnabled?(true/false)
```

Then inside `cellForRowAt` do

```
 cell.callBackHide = { [weak self] enabled in
     self.tableView?.isEnabled = enabled 
 }
```

**Or try**

```
guard let table = self.superView?.superView as? UITableView else { return }
table.isEnabled = true/false
```